# Task Scheduler Error code needs translation

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

In setting up a new task running on our Windows 2008 R2 server I get this error message:
An error has occurred for task TEST error message: the following error was reported: 2147943729.

I have searched all over for this specific error code but no hits.
Anyone knows how I can get more info?

Comment: Do you get the error when you try to insert the task into the task scheduler?

Comment: Does the task run ok by itself? i.e. when you run it manually?

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to hex to get 0x80070531.  That makes it a fatal error (8), produced by Windows (7) with error code 0x531 = 1329:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_INVALID_WORKSTATION
//
// MessageText:
//
// Logon failure: user not allowed to log on to this computer.
//
#define ERROR_INVALID_WORKSTATION        1329L
```

You will need to give the scheduled task a valid user account to run with.

Comment: 1329 by converting the 0531 at the end back to decimal, right?